# Byte Json cannot be loaded after transforming to string json

Tags: python, json, django

The Json that its receiving in message is a byte json like so: `b'{"_timestamp": 1636472787, "actual": 59.9, "target": 60.0}'`
The Code is supposed to change the byte Json to String Json and load it to access the items but when I load it I get the following error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Code:

```
import json
def handle_msg(topic, message):
    m = message.decode("Utf-8")
    print(json.loads(m))
```

Comment: What output do you get if you `print(m)` before the call to `json.loads()`?

Comment: {"_timestamp": 1636473784, "actual": 28.0, "target": 0.0}

Comment: Can you add the full traceback/error message to the question?

Comment: I was receiving NULL messages thats where the error came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happening because you message is null value not as you expected
if you write the following it will work for you
the following running for me

```
message = b'{"_timestamp": 1636472787, "actual": 59.9, "target": 60.0}'
topic ="what ever"
import json 
def handle_msg(topic, message):
    m = message.decode("Utf-8")
    print(json.loads(m))
handle_msg(topic, message)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was so tunnelvisioned that I was not expecting one message to be None. I am receiving loads of messages so I just need to wrap it in a try except block